# Keep ZSH config when entering remote machine via ssh

Tags: ubuntu, oh-my-zsh

I was wondering if there was a way to keep the formatting, functionality and aliases I've set up with ZSH locally whenever I enter a remote machine via SSH. Currently, as I would expect without any type of configuration, it defaults to a standard terminal.

I am on Ubuntu 19.10 running zsh 5.7.1 in the terminal application.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at this repository:

https://github.com/romkatv/zsh4humans

It advertises itself [with](https://github.com/romkatv/zsh4humans#ssh):

> SSH
>
> When you connect to a remote host over SSH, your local Zsh for Humans
> environment gets teleported over to it. The first login to a remote
> host may take some time. After that it's as fast as normal ssh.

Under the hood it is [described](https://github.com/romkatv/zsh4humans/blob/v4/fn/-z4h-help-ssh) to work like this:

> 1. Archives Zsh config files on the local host and sends them to the
>    remote host.
> 2. Extracts Zsh config files on the remote host.
> 3. Sources %U.zshenv%u with Z4H_BOOTSRAPING=%F{3}'1'%f, which starts the usual
>    %Bzsh4humans%b bootstrap process.

Maybe this is not as specific answer that you would be happy with but you can dig there to find something useful.